# Windows Batch check hostname if contains four or three chars then do

Tags: windows, file, batch-file

The problem im facing, is that i wanted a batch script which worked like this :

Check for computer hostname

1. If computer hostname starts with A405 or A408 or A410 or A417 or LAS (i red that i can use %var:0,4% or smthing similar to check the full hostname for the first 4 characters, for the LAS its 3 chars - all pc hostname's are given like this %CLASSROOM%-%PCNUM%)
2. Then launch corresponding reg file from network disk (each regfile disables PROXY and sets a new default and different homepage for each class, the regfiles are done already)
   A405 -> J:/1.reg
   A408 -> J:/2.reg
   etc
3. after that launch internet explorer with -k enabled. ( start iexplore -k )

But i couldn't get how to make %computername% a variable, because set host=%computername%, returns %computername% not the actual name of the workstation, and how to check with previously stated - %host:0,4%, and for LAS the %host:0,3% and check for the first 4 characters.
I'm sorry if im not making myself clear enough.

I tried to use this script from SO:

```
@echo off

rem Change this for testing, remove for production
set computername=xyz

set dropLoc=machine-abc

if "%computername%" == "xyz" (
  set dropLoc=machine-xyz
)

echo %dropLoc%
```

But I couldn't do it.

Comment: The substring syntax is `%host:~0,3%` notice the `~`

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off

rem Check "%computername%" vs. 4 chars. long names:
set regFile=0
for %%a in (A405 A408 A410 A417) do (
   set /A regFile+=1
   if "%computername:~0,4%" equ "%%a" goto found
)

rem Check "%computername%" vs. 3 chars. long names:
for %%a in (LAS) do (
   set /A regFile+=1
   if "%computername:~0,3%" equ "%%a" goto found
)

echo No matching hostname found
goto :EOF

:found
echo Hostame found, reg file: J:/%regFile%.reg
```

Comment: I have 2 additional sub-questions :

1) the naming of regfiles, will be 1.reg = 405, 2.reg = 408 etc ?
or will it just have for 4char A405-A417 1 reg file and for LAS 1 reg file ?>
2) After the :found instance, how can i safely continue, to add start iexplore -k ? or i just add after echo Hostname Found, "pause"  and then the last commandline ?>

Comment: 1) I followed your indications: A405->1.reg, A408->2.reg, and I assumed that "etc" means: A410->3.reg, A417->4.reg and LAS->5.reg, but this may be changed if you specify how you want to change it (I also assumed that may be several 3 chars. names). 2) Yes, just insert the following commands at the right place...